# Can you choose which ES6 features to transpile with Babel?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

For example, is there an option to pass Babel to only transpile arrow functions, or let/const?

My use case is to remove transpiling for certain features as browsers widely support them.

Comment: Read the manual. Try `babel --help`. Look for "transformers", "whitelist" etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can pass a `whitelist` option to specify specific transformations to run, or a `blacklist` to specific transformations to disable.

They are listed here: http://babeljs.io/docs/advanced/transformers/. See also: http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/

#### Update:

The answer above applies to Babel 5. In Babel 6, all plugins are explicitly enabled either directly or via "presets" which bundle plugins together. You cannot blacklist specific plugins, but you may list only the plugins you want, excluding the ones you do not wish to run.

Comment: I added an answer because I wanted to help, but I also voted to close because I agree with you.