# Using the whitelist option with Babel's external-helpers

Tags: javascript, babeljs, rollupjs

I'm trying to use Rollup with Babel's `external-helpers`.  It works, but it's dropping a bunch of babel helpers which I don't even need, for example asyncGenerator.

The docs [show a whitelist option](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/external-helpers/) but I can't get it to work

```
rollup.rollup({
    entry: 'src/buttonDropdown.es6',
    plugins: [
        babel({
            presets: ['react', ['es2015', { modules: false }], 'stage-2'],
            plugins: [['external-helpers', { whitelist: ['asyncGenerator'] }]]
        })
    ]
})
```

The above has no effect: all Babel helpers are still dropped into my resulting bundle.

What is the correct way of using this feature, and is there a full list of which helpers' names the whitelist array takes?

Or is there some other Rollup plugin I should be using with Rollup to automatically "tree shake" the babel external helpers.

Comment: does the same error also occur in external-helpers 2? https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-external-helpers-2

Comment: @pritishvaidya Well there's no error either way - the problem is that the whitelist option is being ignored, and so helpers I don't need are being dropped into my dist.  There's no change with `external-helpers-2` - same problem.

Comment: alright i'll try to find some result or help with tree shaking.

Comment: can you include minimal code to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Problem

**The `babel-plugin-external-helpers` plugin is not responsible for injecting those dependencies in the final bundle.**
The only thing it controls is that how the generated code will access those functions. For example:

```
classCallCheck(this, Foo);
// or
babelHelpers.classCallCheck(this, Foo);
```

It is needed so all `rollup-plugin-babel` needs to do is to inject `babelHelpers` in every module.

**The documentation is misleading, the `whitelist` options is not on the `external-helpers` plugin**. It's on the [completely separate module and command line tool called `babel-external-helpers`](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/master/packages/babel-core/src/tools/build-external-helpers.js#L86), which is actually responsible for generating `babelHelpers`.

**It's `rollup-plugin-babel` what is injecting `babelHelpers`.** And does it using a trick to modularize the final code. It calls `babel-external-helpers` to generate the helpers, [and ignores the whitelist parameter](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-babel/blob/master/src/index.js#L40). See [my issue requesting to expose an option](https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-babel/issues/91).

This approach is correct, because rollup will tree-shake the unused helper functions. However some of the helpers (like `asyncGenerator`) are written in a way that is hard to detect if the initialization has any side effects, thus preventing removal during tree-shaking.

## Workaround

I [forked `rollup-plugin-babel`](https://github.com/sorgloomer/rollup-plugin-babel) and created a PR which exposes the whitelist option of building babelHelpers in the plugin's options. It can be used this way:

```
require("rollup").rollup({
  entry: "./src/main.js",
  plugins: [
    require("rollup-plugin-babel")({
      "presets": [["es2015", { "modules": false }]],
      "plugins": ["external-helpers"],
      "externalHelpersWhitelist": ['classCallCheck', 'inherits', 'possibleConstructorReturn']
    })
  ]
}).then(bundle => {
  var result = bundle.generate({
    format: 'iife'
  });
  require("fs").writeFileSync("./dist/bundle.js", result.code);
}).then(null, err => console.error(err));
```

*Note that I didn't publish distribution version on npm, you will have to clone the git repo and build it using `rollup -c`.*

## Solution

In my opinion the right solution would be to somehow detect or tell rollup that those exports are pure, so can be removed by tree shaking. I will start a discussion about it on github after doing some research.

Comment: Outstanding - thank you so much!  I'll leave this open *for now* but it'll be my pleasure to put you over the 10K mark very soon :)

Comment: @AdamRackis Thank **you**, it was an interesting research.

Answer (score 1):

As I have found in this particular [issue](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/3016) in the GitHub page.

The Babel member [Hzoo](https://github.com/hzoo) suggests that

> **Right now the intention of the preset is to allow people to use it without customization - if you want to modify it then you'll have to
>   just define plugins yourself or make your own preset.**

But still if you want to exclude  a specific plugin from the default preset then here are some steps.
As suggested by [Krucher](https://github.com/kruncher) you can create a fork to the undesirable plugin in the following way

- First one is by **forking** technique

  ```
  "babel": {
  "presets": [
    "es2015"
  ],
  "disablePlugins": [
      "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"
  ]
  ```

  }

But if two or more people want to include the es2015-with-commonjs then it would be a problem.For that you have to `define your own preset` or `extend` the preset of that module.

- The second method would involve the [tree-shaking](http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/webpack-tree-shaking.html)  as shown in this article done by [Dr. Axel Rauschmayer](http://rauschma.de/).
  According to the article `webpack2` is used with the `Babel6`.
  This helps in removal of the unwanted imports that might have been used anywhere in the project in two ways

  1. First, all ES6 module files are combined into a `single bundle file`. In that file, exports that were not imported anywhere are not exported, anymore.
  2. Second, the bundle is `minified`, while eliminating `dead code`. Therefore, entities that are neither exported nor used inside their modules do not appear in the minified bundle. Without the first step, dead code elimination would never remove exports (registering an export keeps it alive).

Other details can be found in the article.

Simple implemetation is referred as [here](https://github.com/rauschma/tree-shaking-demo).

- The third method involves creating your own preset for the particular module.

Creating aplugin and greating your own preset can be implemented according to the documentation [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/)

Also as an extra tip you should also use [babel-plugin-transforn-runtime](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-runtime/)
If any of your modules have an external dependancy,the `bundle` as a whole will have the same `external dependancy` whether or not you actually used it which may have some `side-effects`.

There are also a lot of issues with tree shaking of rollup.js as seen in this [article](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#tree-shaking-doesnt-seem-to-be-working)

> Also as shown in the presets [documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/)

**Enabled by default**

These plugins have no effect anymore, as a newer babylon version enabled them by default

```
- async-functions (since babylon 6.9.1)
- exponentiation-operator (since babylon 6.9.1)
- trailing-function-commas (since babylon 6.9.1)**
```

Also the concept of whitelisting and blacklisting the plugins has benn brilliantly explained by [loganfsmyth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/785065/loganfsmyth) here in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079261/can-you-choose-which-es6-features-to-transpile-with-babel).

> **you can pass a whitelist option to specify specific transformations to run, or a blacklist to specific transformations to disable.**
>
> **You cannot blacklist specific plugins, but you may list only the plugins you want, excluding the ones you do not wish to run.**

**Update :**

According to this [article](http://jamesknelson.com/the-six-things-you-need-to-know-about-babel-6/) here is an important update -

> "The `--external-helpers` option is now a plugin. To **avoid repeated inclusion of Babel’s helper functions**, you’ll **now need to install and apply the babel-plugin-transform-runtime package**, and then **require the babel-runtime package within your code** (yes, **even if you’re using the polyfill**)."

Hope this may solve your problem

Hope it may help you.

Comment: The GitHub issue you shared was about something else.  I *think* they're talking about customizing presets, though I could be wrong.  In any event, presets *are* customizable now (as you can see with my call to es2015 above) and Babel's own docs specify the very whitelist option I'm trying to use.  Nonetheless, thanks for the good info. +1

Comment: yea presets are customisable now,but im trying to specify some other methods too which can be implemented and there might be some polyfills included which could cause some side effects to your bundling process.So the webpack 2 along with the babel 6 tree shaking provides the best approach in these cases